# jQuery Mobile does not listen to e.PreventDefault

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I would like to ask help on jQuery Mobile plugin conflict on my main scripts. Im trying to create another version of the website, which is the mobile version with a bought template that uses jQuery Mobile. Still the site is in CodeIgniter framework based from the web version.

In my main scripts, I have a preventDefault() function on every form submit to display the validation errors. Then when I migrated the site I'm working on with the bought Mobile Template, it seems not to listen to the preventDefault(). whenever I submit a form, it will show validation errors but will change the page seconds after before I could read it. It refreshes the site.

My script looks something like the code below. This works on my web version. >>>

```
$('form#frm-signup-updates').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    $.post(base_url+'home/subscribe', $('#frm-signup-updates').serialize(), function(data){

        if(data == 'success'){
            loadpopup();
        }
        else{
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("span.error-notif#name").append(json.name);
            $("span.error-notif#email").append(json.email);
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` isn't constrained to jQuery its part of the javascript language.

Comment: @Class, while that's true, [jQuery also has its own `event.preventDefault()` method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `return false` to block `submit`.

```
$('form#frm-signup-updates').submit(function(e){

    $.post(base_url+'home/subscribe', $('#frm-signup-updates').serialize(), function(data){

        if(data == 'success'){
            loadpopup();
        }
        else{
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            $("span.error-notif#name").append(json.name);
            $("span.error-notif#email").append(json.email);
        }

    });
    return false;
});
```

**UPDATE:**
Well, I checked source code of jQuery Mobile and found that jQM prevent form submit by default, and handle with ajax.

```
        //bind to form submit events, handle with Ajax
        $.mobile.document.delegate("form", "submit", function(event) {
            var formData = getAjaxFormData($(this));

            if (formData) {
                $.mobile.changePage(formData.url, formData.options);
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```

`preventDefault` is invalid because `submit` is done by `$.mobile.changePage` not browser.

So, if wanna prevent `submit`, that is `$.mobile.changePage`, I have two suggestions:

**1. Add 'data-ajax=false' attribute to `form` element**

[demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/WurHB/)

**2. Do ajax when submit button clicked**

[demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/WurHB/1/)

Comment: [The difference between `return false;` and `e.preventDefault();`](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)

Comment: @Fly_pig Thanks! I never thought I did it wrong-- misuse of preventDefault(). Maybe I haven't really understood their difference, because during the website version, it got no problems using preventDefault() and I thought it was ok.

Comment: @user2567536 I confused `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation`, but known that `return false` equals they two.And, I've updated my answer.